# Hibernate (Mapping to Cross Reference table)

Tags: java, hibernate, data-modeling

I'm trying to do the following (very contrived example):

I have two tables A & B which form a many-to-many relationship for which I've created a mapping table A_B. I then have a table C which forms a one to many relationship with the mapping table A_B.

```
tableA
------
a_id [pk]
```

then

```
tableB
------
b_id [pk]
```

then

```
tableA_B
-------
a_id [pk]
b_id [pk]
```

then

```
tableC
------
c_id [pk]
```

then

```
tableC_AB
---------
c_id [pk]
a_id [pk]
b_id [pk]
```

So in Hibernate I created entities for A, B & C...

```
ClassA {
    ....
    @JoinTable(
        name="A_B",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="a_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="b_id")}
    )
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private Set<B> bset = new HashSet<B>();
}
```

then (the inverse relationship)

```
ClassB {
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="bset")
    private Set<A> subjects = new HashSet<A>();
}
```

This creates the first mapping A_B however I'm not sure how to create the mapping C_AB in hibernate. I don't even have entities for A_B (only exist in the database) so how do I go about this?

Any help appreciated.

Cheers,

JLove

Answer (score 0):

I 'd like to suggest that independent association/join/link entity class should be used instead of implicit many-to-many table.  for there is no joined-tables in the real-world which have no additional fields such as created time, created by, agreement and employment contract and so on.

so I mean:

- tableA_B should be mapped to independent entity and there are must be some additional fields when two things are linked together.
- tableC_AB should be mapped to independent entity too.
- When we want to find collectiion fields, we can find and fetch collectiion fields by HQL with order.
- many-to-many is bugy and the association table can't have additional fields but it should have

Comment: Thanks for the reply... Can I ask if I'm understanding you answer correctly. You suggest that instead of using a mapping table (which I currently have) I should create a new entity to model the relationship... would this entity not then just be a mapping entity (like I already have using the ManyToMany? Just so you know, my table is truly just a mapping... I have no need for additional fields.